# How to pass data to the activity that is a member of a TabHost

Tags: android

My application contains a tabhost, added a tab with by passing an Intent object as content.
And it is working fine, but when i pass data to this intent object using putExtra() method, i'm getting the following exceptions:

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1078): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.abc.xz.LIST (has extras) }

can anyboyd help me to resolve this..

Thanks,
venkat

Comment: Please post some code that can help us to solve your problem.Also check the mainfest file that you have registered your activity.

Comment: Hi Shashank, I have added the activity in the manifest file, If i dont use putExtras(), it is working fine...

Comment: Can please edit the question & post the code how you are passing the data through Intent to another activity.

Comment: Hi Shashnak, sorry, i was wrong. I have added the Acitity in the manifest file but the intent filter is wrong..
Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, It is working perfectly, but the problem is with the wrong intent filter in the Manifest file.